# As Pakistani Passport holder and a Schengen visa holder do i need aTransit Visa for Manchester

Tags: visas, transit

I am Pakistani passport holder and I have a Schengen Visa and studying in Sweden going back to my country and the flight I booked has a 21-hour layover at Manchester do I need to apply for a transit visa.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not leaving the airport, or not switching airports, and your transit is less than 24 hours, then you do not need a transit visa; on the basis of your Schengen D visa.

See the [requirements](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/pakistan/transit/somewhere_else/no):

> Exemptions You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> - a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used
>     for travel to any country)
> - a residence permit issued by Australia or
>     New Zealand
> - a common format residence permit issued by an European
>     Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland
> - a resident permit issued by
>     Canada after 28 June 2002
> - a uniform format category D visa for entry
>     into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland
> - an
>     Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’
>     section)
> - a Schengen Approved Destination Scheme (ADS) group tourism
>     visa where the holder is travelling to the Schengen country that
>     issued the visa a flight ticket from the Schengen area, if you can
>     prove that you entered the Schengen area in the previous 30 days on
>     the basis of a valid Schengen ADS visa
> - a valid USA I-551 Temporary
>     Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp version will not be
>     accepted)
> - a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or
>     after 21 April 1998
> - an expired USA I-551 Permanent Residence card
>     issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998, with a valid I-797 letter
>     authorising extension a valid standalone US Immigration Form 155A/155B
>     issued by the USA (attached to a sealed brown envelope)
>
> All visas and
>   residence permits must be valid.

Comment: thank you so much for reply but sorry for being naive, I don't know what category D visa is but I will be having flight tickets on me for a round trip back to Amsterdam. Can you please tell me if that would work and can i go out of the airport as i said it is a layover of 21 hours

Comment: This is not all. OP can also pass through border control and get out of airport on a TVOW.